# Note Board Web Part - avoid entire page scroll

Tags: 2010, web-part, sitepages

Is it possible to avoid entire page scoll of Note Board Web Part while note count increases ?
Instead of reducing display note count value,I would prefer web part level scrolling.

Comment: Did you try specifying the Web Part width and height property?

Comment: Yes, I tried with fixed web part height(200 px) but it's not working.